# Can you help me identify what is said in this short clip?

Tags: listening

I hope this is ok to ask here.

Could you help me identify what is said in this short clip (6 seconds)?
https://photos.app.goo.gl/gMAKVQXfbLwCqg9r7

The clip is taken from a video tour of a house in London, UK. They are advertising a 4-bed flat as a 3-bed, and the agent explains why. I understand him say "Technically, it's a 4-bed, but now cause (....) they can't rent it as a 4-bed". I can't catch a thing of what he says in the part (....). Could you give me a hand? I'd really appreciate it!

---

I slowed that section down as suggested by Andy Bonner.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/SiUbx5ckSThkTF3d8

With the crucial help of Astralbee I believe the complete transcript is:

"Technically, it's a 4-bed, but now cause of the licensing the landlord can't rent it as a 4-bed"

Comment: Sorry, I can't make it out. And, although there's no specific rule against questions like this, it's not exactly a question about language, but a request for transcription help. You might have some luck using software to slow it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He says:

> "Technically, it is a 4-bed, but now cause of licensing and that I can't rent it as a 4-bed"

I'm 100% sure about the word 'licensing'. I'm a native British English speaker, this is a familiar London accent. I'm almost completely sure he follows with "*and that*" which is a colloquial way of saying "etcetera", or "and so forth".

Comment: The licensing thing was crucial. Thank you! I slowed it down (see the Q edit) and I believe what he says is "now cause of the licensing the landlord can't rent it..."

Comment: Do you agree? Also, he is an agent, not the owner, so I don't think he'd say "I can't rent it"